# How to generate HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I use terraform for create IAM User.
How to use terraform for generate HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit ?

My code :

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "gitlab" {
  name = "user-gitlab"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "gitlab" {
  name       = "iam-gitlab"
  users      = ["${aws_iam_user.gitlab.name}"]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitPowerUser"
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Use data.external to execute a CLI script:

```
credentials=$(aws --profile dev iam list-service-specific-credentials \
  --user-name jenkins --service-name codecommit.amazonaws.com --query 'ServiceSpecificCredentials[0]')

if [[ $credentials == "null" ]]; then
  credentials=$(aws --profile dev iam create-service-specific-credential --user-name jenkins \
  --service-name codecommit.amazonaws.com --query ServiceSpecificCredential)
fi
echo "$credentials"
```

Then the terraform:

```
data "external" "jenkins" {
  program = ["${path.root}/jenkins.sh"]
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "jenkins_cc_id" {
  name      = "${local.jenkins}/codecommit_https_user"
  value     = "${lookup(data.external.jenkins.result, "ServiceUserName", "")}"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "jenkins_cc_p" {
  name      = "${local.jenkins}/codecommit_https_pass"
  value     = "${lookup(data.external.jenkins.result, "ServicePassword", "")}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature has been implemented in 4.1.0 (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.1.0/CHANGELOG.md).
Take a look at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_service_specific_credential#service_specific_credential_id

```
resource "aws_iam_service_specific_credential" "example" {
  service_name = "codecommit.amazonaws.com"
  user_name    = aws_iam_user.example.name
}
```

Comment: Please fix the link to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_service_specific_credential#service_specific_credential_id and I upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no support for this API in Terraform.  I recommend that you post a feature request in the [AWS provider GitHub repo](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws).